# How to upload file in external ip address vbscript

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic, vbscript, ftp

I'm using vbscript in asp classic. I also used the FreeASPUpload class.. I want to upload file not in local, but to a server using its IP address as path..

Here is the code working if i will upload in local..

```
  Dim uploadsDirVar
  uploadsDirVar = Server.MapPath("../temp/")

  Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
  Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)
```

But i want to upload it in a path with an ip address.. Below are the codes I tried but its resulting in HTTP 500 Internal Server Error..

```
Dim uploadsDirVar
uploadsDirVar = "\\123.45.6.789\DocFolder\"

Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)
```

I already mapped the folder \123.45.6.789\DocFolder\ in my local because of the login. I also tried codes with credentials but still same error.. See below:

```
Dim ServerShare 
Dim UserName 
Dim Password 
Dim NetworkObject 
Dim FSO

ServerShare = "\\123.45.6.789\DocFolder\"
UserName = "domain\username"
Password = "password"

Set NetworkObject = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "", ServerShare, False, UserName, Password

Dim uploadsDirVar
uploadsDirVar = "\\123.45.6.789\DocFolder\"

Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)
```

Still same result.. Can anyone help? I'm new in asp classic and vbscript especially in uploading of files and also its behavior. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your website in IIS typically runs under a machine-specific user account for IIS (IUsr_computername). It won't have any privileges on the remote machine you are trying to access over the network. You need to create a user in a domain that both your IIS machine and the remote share are in, and set that website to run as this new domain user. You can then give that new domain user privileges to read/write in the folder you're sharing on the remote machine.

Comment: Do you mean I will create a new user to the IP address where I want to upload the file and add it in its IIS? Do you have any idea how to do it in IIS 7 in winserver 2008? I'm new in configuring this matter. Thanks

Comment: Talk to your network admin about getting a new domain user created. The domain user can then be used for running the virtual website and have access to your shared folder on the remote machine. Do you have a network admin?

Comment: None, but I have access both on the server of the website where the functionality of upload.. And I also have access to the server of where the folder where I want to upload from the deployed website.

Can you instruct me how to configure it? Or do you have any links of tutorial? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this answer on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/a/337841), which should get you there. You might also want to read [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities), and [How to access network files from IIS applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/207671).

Comment: on this link http://superuser.com/questions/337827/permissions-issue-with-asp-net-application-using-network-share/337841#337841, i cant do the 3rd step, the IIS is IIS 6

Comment: already saw it. I tried to change the user (from NetworkService)to IUSR_SHARE but the problem is, when I run the website, it is Service Unavailable..

Comment: [Configuring Application Pools in IIS 6.0](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/f05a7c2b-36b0-4b6e-ac7c-662700081f25.mspx?mfr=true)